# Magento Custom Options - add a CSS className to the custom option field

Tags: magento

I want to specify a CSS class to apply to my custom options fields. This will allow me to use more robust JavaScript selectors on the product view page.

So in Product>Custom options in the Admin I want to have something like this: 
[image: Added CSS class in Custom Options]

Where I've added the CSS Class attribute to the field.

This can be added simply enough in the adminhtml template file:

```
app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\product\edit\options\option.phtml
```

But I don't know which files I need to override/extend in order to get it saving that extra attribute when I click Save. 
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: have a look at this link http://phprelated.myworks.ro/how-to-override-rewrite-model-class-in-magento/

Comment: and look at this more intersting one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676380/magento-separate-stylesheet-per-parent-category

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the links, but I think you may have misunderstood. My question's not a general one about customizing magento. It's about Extending a specific part: the Custom Options menu within the Product Admin. It's for when you want to let a user customize a product, e.g: Type their name so it appears on a t-shirt.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you do this for the option type "text". You need to provide a way to enter, edit, store, and output this new property.

**To Enter**: As you have already found out, you must edit the backend template files. app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\product\edit\options\type\text.phtml:

[after line 36 enter](https://github.com/varinen/solvingmagento_1.7.0/blob/master/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/options/type/text.phtml#L36)

```
'<th class="type-last last"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Custom CSS') ?> </th>'+
```

and [after line 47](https://github.com/varinen/solvingmagento_1.7.0/blob/master/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/options/type/text.phtml#L47):

```
'<td class="type-last last"><input type="text" class="input-text" name="product[options][{{option_id}}][custom_css]" value="{{custom_css}}"></td>'+
```

this will add a field to enter the custom css class to.

**To Edit**: You need to rewrite a block that outputs option HTML, so that the new field can get a value from the model. Create a block in your module that is declared as follows:

```
class YourPackage_YourModule_Block_Adminhtml_Option extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option 
{
```

Copy/paste the function `getOptionValues()` from class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option` and add the code

```
##.......code omitted for brevity.......##
$value['sku'] = $this->htmlEscape($option->getSku());
$value['max_characters'] = $option->getMaxCharacters();

// your new field output to the adminhtml form
$value['custom_css'] = $option->getCustomCss();

$value['file_extension'] = $option->getFileExtension();
##.......code omitted  for brevity.......##
```

**To Store**. This is a bit tricky. You need to extend the table catalog_product_option; with one column to store your new property in. Create an install/update script with the following content:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
    ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_option` ADD
    `custom_css` text");
$installer->endSetup();
```

After the script is run, make sure the table has a new column `custom_css`

**To Output**: Finally, update the template file `frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml` by adding a code to output your new custom CSS class property, something like

```
$_option->getCustomCss();
```

Comment: @OlegIshenko: Thank you for helpful answer, but can I give custom css class to drop-down type and radio button and check-box.