# add a CSS className to the custom option fields like radiobox and select

Tags: magento

I want to group and show in different popup product custom options on frontend on product view page. So I want to give specific class to every product option from backend.
 [refernce from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564542/magento-custom-options-add-a-css-classname-to-the-custom-option-field)
I have use this code but this is giving custom class options only for text-box type options, I want custom class to all type of product options.
Can anyone help?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Something I've used before (although I admit, does not look like a very neat way of doing it) is this in the catalog/product/view/options.phtml:

```
$search = 'product-custom-option';
$replace = 'product-custom-option form-control';

<?php foreach($_options as $_option): ?>
    <?php echo str_replace($search, $replace, $this->getOptionHtml($_option)); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Where the css class 'form-control' was the one I wanted to add.

[EDIT]

In that case, one solution I can think of is this:

- Create a system.xml where you can add the CSS classes for the various option types
- Create a helper class for retrieving the saved CSS classes
- Edit the catalog/product/view/options/type/*.phtml files in your theme where you add the CSS classes by using the helper.

Would that work for you?

Comment: Liked, but this is not what I want, I want to add different custom class for radio-box, different for text-box and so on..., from backend

Comment: Editited my initial answer. Is this more what you're looking for?